# Using git repo as a common base

Tags: git

Say I have some code that forms the basic framework for something cool. I put it in a repo I'll call `cool-app-base`.

Now, I have a few good ideas for some cool apps. I'd like them to use `cool-app-base`, and build from there. Naturally, I have the options to `clone` and orphan, and `fork` and rename, etc. For the sake of examples, let's say I do the best thing for what I want, and create `cool-app-1`.

I don't plan to contribute *back* into `cool-app-base` from `cool-app-1`, so either one would work. But I *do* want to be able to bring any updates I may make to `cool-app-base` into `cool-app-1`.

The thing is, `cool-app-1` shouldn't care about the history of `cool-app-base`. I want to treat these updates as squashed commits, so an update can have a commit message of "update with latest `cool-app-base`" and be done. This makes `fork` less appealing, but it also sounds like my only option is manually merging the `cool-app-base` code changes into `cool-app-1` so I can control the commit history.

My question is: How can I do this better/"correctly"? I'm sure there are some funky `git merge` options I could use, but I'm not well-versed enough yet to confidently explore them.

**Clarification:** `cool-app-base` isn't a library, but a set of config files. While they could certainly be broken up and imported individually, my intent is to maintain them bundled together. I want to have the files of `cool-app-base` form the root of `cool-app-1`, not be nested in a sub-directory. The actual problem I'm trying to solve is not needing to recreate my package file, directory structure, and a set of carefully-and-generically-constructed scripts every time I want to spin-up a new project. If my configs were in a sub-directory, I'd still need to create references down to them, in what I would consider just more boilerplate code.

Also, while I consider the concept to be language-agnostic, I'm working in `JavaScript` with `node` and `npm`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my opinion, you can use [Git Submodules](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Submodules), make `cool-app-base` as a submodule of `cool-app-1`. Then `cool-app-1` will have the subfolder `cool-app-base` in physical file resource, with both repository's Git history not interferenced.

> Git addresses this issue using submodules. Submodules allow you to keep a Git repository as a subdirectory of another Git repository. This lets you clone another repository into your project and keep your commits **separate**.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've added some clarification to my question to hopefully refine the picture of what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: @TheJim01 Do `cool-app-base-v0.1` **inside** `cool-app-1` needs to be updated when `cool-app-base-v0.2` released?

Comment: Great question. That's the idea. If I tweak `cool-app-base`, I can update `cool-app-1` to use the cool new features. It sounds like a recipe for breaking changes to cascade into derivatives, but let's assume tweaks to base will be minor enough to not worry about that. Like maybe only optimizations or dependency version updates count as non-breaking changes.

Comment: @TheJim01 I would still see a submodule as the easiest way to go. Having it as a submodule does not mean that you have to pull updates - your submodule point to the cool-app-base folder can stay at a certain revision forever if it wants or it can branch off - but in either case doing a "pull" from the master branch will always be easy because of the shared history. Once you fork / detatch the history you lose this - of course you can graft two repos together at a later date - but I don't quite understand why you would go to all that pain / effort?

Comment: I'll give it a try, but I don't think it's quite what I want. There's even a chance that what I want isn't possible with git, in which case your suggestion may need to be a workaround that I need to accept.

Comment: @TheJim01 I am considering if direct copy without Git is a simple and good solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, I think you're right. I thought I had stumbled on a solution by using more than one remote, but it only works for an empty repository. I tried using `--allow-unrelated-histories`, but the merges _always_ had conflicts, which also defeats the purpose.

Answer (score 0):

You are not mention your programming language. But most languages come with some kind of package manager:

- JavaScript: npm
- Java: Maven, Gradle
- Python: pip

If you have such a package manager in your language use this in your *app* projects to include your *base* project.

If not, I would suggest [subtree](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/git-subtree.1.html) instead of submodules. You are able to include the *base* project into a subdirectory of your *app* projects. It's like copying the whole file system of one commit into another repo. You can choose if you need the history or not (`squash`).

And later on you can update to a newer version with one command.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've added some clarification to my question to hopefully refine the picture of what I'm trying to accomplish.